# Regex: switch words position in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have text in the following pattern:

```
1 NAME word1 word2 wordn /words/
...
...
1 NAME word1 word2 wordn /words/
```

And I need a regex that will reorder it to:

```
1 NAME /words/ word1 word2 wordn
...
...
1 NAME /words/ word1 word2 wordn
```

I am trying to do this in `notepad++` but can't figure out the regex to match *n* number of words until the character `/`

Please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Find:** `([^ ]+) ([^/]+)/([^/]+)/`

- `([^ ]+)` Matches "name" as anything but a space into group `\1` (followed by a space)
- `([^/]+)` Matches "all words" as anything up until the first `/` into group `\2`
- `/([^/]+)/` Matches anything between `/` and `/` into group `\3`

**Replace With:** `/\3/ \2\1`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
(?<=1 NAME )(\S+ ){n}/words/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in in MS Word (and I think in Visual Studio as well). Here is how it is done in [MS Word](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-advanced-HA102350661.aspx#_Toc286834986)

```
Match String: (<*>) (<*>) (<*>) (<*>) (<*>) (<*>)
Replace String: \1 \2 \6 \3 \4 \5
```

In MSWord it does not specifically say regular expression but it might be using it at the back end. Note that it has problem matching \word\ that is words staring with backslash(). You may want to remove backslash from the word just to make sure it work.